# Does MySQL order PK-field by default during only PK select?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from two much big table using join:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  
  e.*
FROM `table_A` e 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT id FROM `table_B` /* FORCE index (primary, index_A) */
    WHERE id > 338107  AND `index_field_A` = 900000000 AND `index_field_B` = 1 
 ORDER BY id) AS c 
        ON `c`.`id` = `e`.`fk_id` 
    WHERE e.`some_field` IS NULL; 
    LIMIT 2000;

    /*  BEST EXPLAIN RESULT
    USING intersect(index_A,index_B); USING WHERE; USING INDEX
    */
```

I store current id at the application side (338107) to be able to get total result by batching (from start id to max id)
There are no problem if I get rid off **ORDER BY id** But I am not sure that MySQL order PK by default.
There are no problem TOO if I use separate SELECT without JOIN :

```
SELECT id FROM `table_B` WHERE id > 338107  
AND `index_field_A` = 900000000 AND `index_field_B` = 1 ORDER BY id
```

but it is useless

A little better EXPLAIN I can get if I forcing index :

```
FORCE index (primary, index_A)
```

But it too far from good.

Can I get rid of ORDER BY id without negative aftermath?

Addition : ordering PK field is autoincrement, InnoDB tables

Comment: Have tried using a more conventional JOIN (without the subquery) yet?

Comment: I can't try it exact now (for huge real data), but you are possible wright and simple JOIN get more effective

Comment: But it became to filesorting : USING WHERE; USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort

Comment: What  engine are these tables using? MyISAM? InnoDB?

Comment: InnoDB tables  (oh yea, comments must be  at least 15 characters in length)

Comment: I think the results without any direct or indirect sort (like using `UNION`) comes sorted by arbitrary, I think also you don't need `ORDER BY` in your inner select ;).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_A`
WHERE `some_field` IS NULL
   AND `fk_id` IN (
        SELECT `id` 
        FROM `table_B`
        WHERE id > 338107 AND `index_field_A` = 900000000 AND `index_field_B` = 1 
      )
ORDER BY `fk_id`
;
```

or

```
SELECT e.*
FROM `table_B` AS c 
   LEFT JOIN `table_A` AS e 
      ON c.`id` = e.`fk_id` 
      AND e.`someField` IS NULL
WHERE c.id > 338107 
   AND c.`index_field_A` = 900000000 
   AND c.`index_field_B` = 1
HAVING e.fk_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY e.`fk_id`
;
```

Comment: The FIRST QUERY IS good ON EXPLAIN but works too slow
The SECOND IS wrong : NO ANY LEFT joining, HAVING must be IS NULL,
But the most reason :
The target issue IS "ordering". You just IGNORE it. I can REMOVE my own ORDER BY line AND it will WORK fine.

I can USE SIMPLE JOIN but it will make MySQL's crafty "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
which is not convenient for much large tables.

Comment: I'm not sure what significance to attribute to the things you capitalize, but to address your concerns... What is the problem with LEFT JOINing? HAVING needs to be NOT NULL to give you results equivalent to the first query (i.e. turning it into a standard INNER JOIN). The ORDERing you supplied, commented out, in the question would have had unclear affects on the ordering of the final results; but I just added some above. The WHERE I used in the second option should take advantage of your index on table_B, and the JOIN to table_A should end up using the INDEXes on table_B.id and table_A.fk_id.

Comment: Oh, I see I neglected the `some_field` condition in the second one, correcting that now.